# BSTD inorder traversal produces erroneous behaviour

Tags: java, debugging, recursion, immutability

I have a BSTD implementation which is inserting values incorrectly and I can't find for the life of me what is going on.

```
  EXPECTED ACTUAL  
  -------- ---------- 
  Alex     Janice    
  Carlos   Janice    
  Elton    Janice    
  Janice   Zidane    
  Zidane   Zidane
```

Implementation

```
private Node<K,E> insert(Node<K,E> node, K key, E elem) {

    if (node == null) {
        return new Node<K,E>(null, key, elem, null);
    }

    if (key.compareTo(node.getKey()) < 0) {
        return new Node<K, E>(insert(node.getLeft(), key, elem), key, elem, node.getRight());
    }
    else if (node.getKey().equals(key)) {
        return node;
    }
    else {
        return new Node<K, E>(node.getLeft(), key, elem, insert(node.getRight(), key, elem));
    }
}
```

I've tried debugging this for over an hour with no luck, any ideas where is my recursion going wrong?

Comment: can you provide example inputs on these?  Just to be sure we're on the same page.  Also the code that calls it would be useful, in case the error is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the new node, that should take its content from node in general.

It must be the equals/compare. More solid code would be:

```
int comparison = key.compareTo(node.getKey());
if (comparison < 0) {
    return new Node<K, E>(
        insert(node.getLeft(), key, elem),
        node.getKey(), node.getElem(),
        node.getRight());
}
else if (comparison == 0) {
    return node;
}
else {
    return new Node<K, E>(
        node.getLeft(),
        node.getKey(), node.getElem(),
        insert(node.getRight(), key, elem));
}
```

This relies only on compareTo.

Comment: this is solid advice, even if it turns out this is not the root issue

Comment: @MarshallTigerus yes, I realized, that this could not be a method / field references. Thanks for the mild critics